# ASP.net SSRS ReportViewer session timeout KeepSessionAlive not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I have this strange problem.  We are using SSRS ReportViewer control hosted in ASP.net page.  ReportViewer control is rendering reports fine.  But when user remains idle for some period, it throws "ASP.net session is expired" exception.

Although I am not able to track exactly when ASP.net session expires, I understand why it would throw this exception.  But I have already set KeepSessionAlive property of ReportViewer control to true.  Shouldn't this help the asp.net session to keep going infinitely?

One more thing is - I used Fiddler and chrome dev tools to trace if ReportViewer control is pinging report server periodically to keep session alive.  But I cannot see any such web requests being made by the ReportViewer Control.  What could the reason for this?  How can I keep sessions alive and avoid this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: I think I am having the same problem.  Would like to know if you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe setting the session timeout directly in the report server side properties?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/server-properties-advanced-page-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017